# TinyMCE adds two dots to the beginning of the source of the image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tinymce

I have a react blog web app where i use TinyMCE as text editor. When i try to add an image with the editor, the source of image returns correctly. but when i try to open the source-plugin i see that it changes the image source and adds two dots ("..") at the beginning of it. I also have a custom image upload handler, which sends the location (source) for the image and it sends te location correctly. Is there a solution for it?

Here are screenshots of the problem:

[Add Image Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsBJG.png)

[How the editor seems after adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zfrj.png)

[when i try to see the source, double dots are added to the beginning of the src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QucgB.png)

Comment: Can you post your full tinymce.init() configuration? The issue could be related to your URL handling configuration: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is tied to what TinyMCE refers to as URL Handling.  There are a variety of options you can use to control what TinyMCE will do URLs when you add them to the editor:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

If you don't want a relative URL like you currently see you can use the settings referenced in that section to have TinyMCE do something different with the URL.